# Visual Studio 2015 Go To Definition going to wrong class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I just started having a problem with Visual Studio 2015 in C++ code.  When I hit F12 to go do definition, I get taken to the wrong class.  Inside of the solution, there are multiple projects with different classes that have the same method name.  Here's a simple diagram of the project/class structure.

```
Project1
   Class1
     Initialize();
Project2
   Class2
     Initialize();
```

Class2 uses Class1 from Project1.  If I'm working within Class2 and hit F12 on Class1.Initialize(), I get taken to the Class2.Initialize function.

It's almost like Visual Studio is only looking at the function name and starts searching within the current project.

I've tried restarting Visual Studio and deleting the .suo files.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well a lot of times, especially when classes with same name but different namespace are involved, or just with different class names but same method name.
Unfortunately I see the same problem in Visual Studio 2017.

I suppose the cause may be some deficiency in the Intellisense parsing part of the IDE.